# How can I duplicate all variables, objects, etc. referenced within a function via a function pointer in c++

Tags: c++, excel, vba, multithreading, com

So I am wondering how I would go about duplicating all referenced objects/variables within the scope of a function/method from a function pointer.

A little bit more background on the issue -> I am passing a function pointer to a C++ method from VBA using the AddressOf method. The idea is to duplicate the underlying variables/objects within that VBA method so that the function can be ran on multiple threads. At the moment if I try and directly callback the function from my c++ function on more than 1 thread it instantly crashes, and I know this is because VBA runs in an STA. My though process is that if I can almost duplicate the objects that are necessary for the function, I can then avoid the issue of referencing an object at the same time (I can have more control in ensuring my code is thread safe). Another alternative I thought of would be to marshal all of the underlying objects through COM, but I have also been unsuccessful in doing this :( I think this would cause more issues anyway as VBA is technically meant to be ran on a single thread.

Any ideas/recommendations would be greatly apreciated, I have been trying to crack this code for a matter of weeks now and am reaching a bit of a brick wall.

Edit - Here is the code to get the function pointer from VBA

```
typedef int (WINAPI *callbackFunc_t)(int, BSTR);

callbackFunc_t callbackFunc;

__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall setCallbackFunction(callbackFunc_t callbackFunc_)
{
     callbackFunc = callbackFunc_;
}
```

Comment: @tadman not a helpful comment

Comment: What does the VBA function and C++ method look like? It's the C++ method that calls the VBA function, right? Is it _only_ that C++ method that calls the VBA function or could it be called from other places too? If it's only that method, what about protecting the VBA call with a mutex?

Comment: Callbacks into VBA crashes not because VBA runs in an STA. COM STA has been invented precisely to prevent multi thread crashes with STA synchronization (message queue). Internal VBA objects (they are not COM objects) just don't support multithreaded access and crash.

Comment: @SimonMourier so how can I duplicate these objects in memory so that each thread has their on version of the objects to access?

Comment: Global variables (in .pas) files are duplicated per thread, if I remember correctly, maybe you can use that somehow.

Comment: i don't follow what the function in your question does that could make VBA crash. `setCallbackFunction` is called _from_ VBA, right? What does the C++ function look like that is actually using the function pointer?

Comment: @TedLyngmo calling back to vba works a treat however, as soon as you attempt to callback from more than 1 thread, it crashes

Comment: @user3551497 I got that, but you haven't shown that code. The code you've shown looks unrelated or .. I'm misunderstanding someting. Here's how I _think_ it could look: https://godbolt.org/z/zEM9Y7cf6

Comment: I'm trying to untangle your question. At first I thought you were asking about C++ reflection.

Comment: @user3551497 Can you please clarify the question? At least show the C++ function(s) that uses `callbackFunc`.